# Unrecognized database format

Tags: c#, database, excel

I would like to ask, why I get this exception when I try to connect excel 2000/3 and also 2010?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace md1_connect
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main (string[] args)
        { 
            string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"Book1.xls\"";            
            OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM[Sheet2$]", MyConn);
            MyConn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataReader.GetDouble(0));
            }
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try compiling your code targeting a 32 bits platform.

Comment: @Tarec "Unrecognized database format" I'm guessing. From the title.

Comment: You can use the [Udl file trick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140076(v=office.10).aspx) to simplify creating the connexion string.

Comment: @Crono1981 I already use "Prefer 32bit", so it wouldnt be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the provider you're using Excel 97-2003 (xls as opposed to xlsx) by appending:

```
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0"
```

E.g.

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"Book1.xls\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0\"";
```

Comment: I tried that, it threw error that connection string is incorrect, when I put that line in.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what the exception is but I may know what you are talking about. You are probably compiling as x64 bit, please force it to run as 32 bit (x86). I believe that setting can be set in your **Project Properties** under **Build Options**

Comment: I have 32bit OS, so it wont compile in 32bits?